# Is there a setting to make LINQ case insensitive by default?

Tags: c#, linq, case-insensitive

A bug has just made me aware that my SQL server is case insensitive and all my LINQ to compare strings are case sensitive.

I'm planning on going through each LINQ where clause and setting the comparison to be case insensitive but I was wondering if there is a way to have LINQ by default to be case insensitive. This would save a lot of work for me.

Alternatively is there another package that would
be the same as LINQ just case insensitive?

Comment: I don't think you really mean LINQ, you're talking about string comparisons

Comment: Note that Linq to Entities will use whatever the collation is on the Sql Server schema so that could be case sensitive or case insensitive. Linq to Objects will always be case sensitive by default because this is just executing the contained expression in memory. Also if you are using Linq to Entities you cannot use a `StringComparison` overload for `string.Equals` as this cannot be translated by default to a sql expression. Even though your code will compile you will get an exception at run time.

Comment: (continued from previous comment) See also [LINQ to Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities)
and [LINQ to Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects) for clarification on these terms.